# Azure Search: How to retrieve more than 1000 documents per request?

Tags: c#, azure

I would like to distinct on a facet field, but only 1000 documents are returned per request. Currently, the Azure Search index has more than 10,000 documents. Is there a way to retrieve all documents for an index in Azure Search?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/search/search-limits-quotas-capacity), which clearly states:

> API Response limits
>
> Maximum 1000 documents returned per page of search results

To get more documents, you can use the top and skip parameters when you are querying the service (just stop when you no longer get any results back).

Answer (score 2):

> How to retrieve more than 1000 documents per request

Unfortunately, it is impossible to get more than 1000 documents per request. We also could get the more limitation from the Kolichikov mentioned [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/search/search-limits-quotas-capacity).

> Is there a way to retrieve all documents for an index in Azure Search?

If using [Azure Search SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Search) is acceptable, we could get the [demo code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-dotnet-sdk) from the azure official document.

Comment: I'm thinking of using Azure Search with multi-facet navigation and have a query... What if a single facet item has more than 1000 items in the index associated to it? Do you have to loop through each page in the index, which could be hundreds of pages just to display that facet in the navigation? Wouldn't that be a performance hit?

Comment: The SDK also implements the Azure Seach REST API, It uses continuetoken to loop through.